# compensation for added responsibility

Tags: compensation

My university employer is piling work on me from two maternity leave women and one other who is out on vacation half of the time! I asked him if I would be compensated for the extra responsibility..he replied "No, we 
Will have to pull together".  I spoke to my hr rep and he says that was a disappointing answer.  What should  my next move be?  What should I say to him, if anything..or should I let Hr handle him?

Comment: In general no one gets a pay raise for helping out during a temporary situation. The time to ask for raise fo this sort is when the person decides not to come back from maternity leave and you are permanenetly assigned the duties.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get paid per hour? If so, you are working more hours and get paid more. If not, there are only so many hours in the day and your employer is going to need to learn how to prioritize.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out what tasks need to be done as a result of the maternity leave and ask you boss which ones he doesn't want you to do.

Make him or her make the Decision

Comment: Let's not make 'passive aggressive' our first response.

Comment: The approach most employers take is to reward you after you've successfully handled additional responsibility rather than to do so when they assign those responsibilities.